# Stuck on a think different questions

Tags: think-different

[image]Been stuck on it for ages it's

3 diamonds = 24

1 hexagon + 1 diamond =25

1 hexagon + 1 star (thing) =8

1 diamond + 1 hexagon + 1 star(thing)=??

Help pleaseeee

Comment: I'm posting this on Puzzling.SE to get more attention

Comment: Give my answer a try and let me know if it works. If so, I'll post the full method.

Comment: I posted on Puzzles, and there's more activity there. (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28030/triple-equation-result-not-mathematical?noredirect=1#comment83155_28030). One question there was - Is it something to do with the colours(red for positive integers, grey for negative?)

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple logic.

- If three diamonds equals 24, 24 / 3 = 8.  One diamond = 8.
- If a diamond + hexagon equals 25, then 25 - 8 = 17.  One hexagon = 17.
- If a hexagon + star = 8, then 8 - 17 = -9.  One star = -9.

That means one diamond (8) + one hexagon (17) + one star (-9) = 8 + 17 - 9.  Which is 16.

Comment: I've tried 16 it's not correct apparently but that's the logic I went with

Comment: I'd recommend adding a picture of the question, then, as from what you've provided, that's the correct answer.

Comment: @Frank This is Think Different. It's probably in base 14 counting the number of corners on the shapes or something.

Comment: @Studoku In which case, we still need the picture, as the text doesn't sufficiently do the question justice.

Comment: I don't know how to add a picture here

Comment: When you edit your question, you should see a little tiny picture icon.  Click that, and point it at the picture.  That should do it.

Comment: Picture added now

Comment: Okay, based on that, I have no idea what it could be if 16 isn't the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be...

> 42

Because...

> The plus signs aren't plus signs. They are also symbols with values.

I'll post the detailed method (and all the head-melting algebra) if OP confirms this is right.

Comment: Nope not 42 either :/

Comment: Damn. Was worth a shot.

Comment: Haha thanks. Still bugging me hopefully someone will get it

Comment: @katie Might be 14. Or 20.

Answer (score 0):

This got [reposted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28030/triple-equation-result-not-mathematical/28076#28076) onto puzzling and I was intrigued by the idea of it not being 16. I downloaded the app answered the first 13 questions and got to this one; I tried 16 and it worked.

Comment: Was just about to link to your answer there ;)

Comment: The next question is, I guess, why 16 does not work for Katie...